# PMF of Bernoulli trials needed to produce at least one success and at least one failure

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X be the number of Bernoulli(p) trials until we get at least one success and at least one failure.

This means we need a string of successes followed by a failure or a string of failures followed by a success.

$P(X = k) = p^{k-1}(1-p) + (1-p)^{k-1}p\quad\quad$  with support $k \geq 2$

Is this correct?
This is similar to but is not the Geometric distribution.
Is there a name for this distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is correct, for $0\lt p\lt 1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is there a name for this distribution?

Comment: I do not know of a name.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks anyway.